# Question about inheritance

Tags: c++

```
class B{
private:
   void DoSomething();
}

class W{
private: 
   class D: public B{
   }

   D d; 
}
```

Can I call private member function in base class of D in the scope of class W?

Comment: Homework?  Why not just compile it and try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope.  You can never call a private member function from anywhere except the class that owns it.  If you want derived classes to be able to access it, declare it protected instead.

You can also declare D to be a 'friend' of class B; that would allow D to access B.DoSomething().  However, this approach is usually frowned upon.

Comment: If DoSomething() is public. It seems that I cannot call it in the scope of W , right?

Comment: If you declare it as public you'll be able to access it from instances of B or instances of any class that extends B. But it has to be from an instance of the class:
B b = new B(); 
b.DoSomething(). 

You can't just access it directly from W.

Answer (score 1):

The function DoSomething can be accessed outside the class only if it is declared as public or private. Besides as mentioned above by Aric, the inherited class can become a friend to achieve the same.

The alternative approach would be to declare/define the function as virtual and do not define the virtual definition for the sub/inherited class. Doing this, will call the function definition for the base class.

Comment: A small correction in the the first line [ of my answer ], i mentioned it as "declared as public or private". It should be "public or protected"

Comment: @Roopesh you can edit the answer to correct it rather than leaving a comment. Just so you know StackOverflow provides the option.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you use the *protected* keyword then you can. The fact that it is a nested class is irrelevant.